# Unable to fetch particular commit hash from gerit error: Server does not allow request for unadvertised object

Tags: git, github

I have updated manifiest file with `clone-depth=1` and when  I try to do the repo sync I am getting the below error. Our gerit config has all the required setting changes for shallow clone

The error:

```
Error:error: Server does not allow request for unadvertised object
Gerit config has the below settings in place
```

The config:

```
[uploadpack]

allowTipSha1InWant = true
allowReachableSHA1InWant = true
allowAnySHA1InWant = true
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the configuration `[uploadpack]` parameters you listed to the `config` file of the Gerrit project (e.g. `git/<project>.git/config`) solved the issue for me.